# Gitlab CI: conditionally ignore 'needs' based on rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-ci-trigger

So I have a pipeline that builds docker images to be used later by other parts of the pipeline. I have set things up so this image-building part of the pipeline only triggers if special tags are included in the commit message, to avoid rebuilding them unless necessary. But there are quite a few images and now I'm trying to figure out how to make this even more fine-grained so that I can rebuild just *some* images when required.

Here's the idea. In my gitlab-ci.yml there is:

```
build-base:
  stage: build-images
  extends: .template_build_image
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: base
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^.*\[build-images\].*$/s'

build-environment:
  stage: build-images
  needs: [build-base]
  extends: .template_build_image
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: environment
  rules:
    - !reference [build-base, rules]

...
<and others>
```

I can add more rules for more tags easily enough, like make a rule for `build-environment` to add it to the pipeline if `[build-environment]` is in the commit message. My problem is that `build-environment` *needs* `build-base`. I.e. gitlab will complain if I try to run `build-environment` without `build-base` in the pipeline. And I don't want to remove these `needs` relationships because when I am running the whole pipeline those relationships are important. I just want to selectively ignore them sometimes when I "manually" want to skip some initial steps in the pipeline (and just use the e.g. `base` image already in my image registry).

Is there some way to achieve this in gitlab CI?

Comment: u can add the check in the job itself and exit with 0 if that condition is met and u dont want the pipeline to proceed furthur

Comment: Hmm yeah good idea, it's a bit of a drag due to the templating but I guess I can cook up some variables to take of it...

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, you can use [`needs:optional:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional). When the needed job is present in the pipeline, it will have the DAG behavior as normal, but if the needed job is excluded due to different `rules:`, it will work as normal without the `needs:` for that job.

```yaml
myjob:
  rules:
    - if: $MAYBE
  # ...

anotherjob:
  needs:
    - job: myjob
      optional: true
```